# Qual è il significato di "smarrono" in questo brano?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nella commedia *Morte accidentale di un anarchico* di Dario Fo, pubblicata da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Allora,
>   cos’hai bisogno dal Bertozzo, che documenti? Sí,
>   detta che prendo nota: la copia del decreto di archiviazione della morte dell’anarchico... va bene, poi te
>   la fa avere... e anche le copie dei verbali... sí, sí è tutto qui nell’archivio... E be’, ci credo dobbiate prepararvi bene tu e l’ex guardiano del campo di concentramento. Se il giudice che arriva è appena una
>   carogna come dicono... Certo che conosco il giudice!
>   Malipiero, si chiama. Mai sentito nominare? Be’, lo
>   sentirai. Uno che s’è fatto il campo di concentramento al tempo dei tedeschi... domanda un po’ al
>   tuo capo se magari se lo ricorda. D’accordo, ti faremo
>   avere subito tutto quanto. Ti saluto... Aspetta, aspetta! Ah, ah, c’è il Bertozzo che ha detto una cosa molto spiritosa... se non t’arrabbi te la dico... Non t’arrabbi? E va bene, allora te la dico: ha detto che... ah,
>   ah... che dopo ’sta visita del giudice revisore ti spediranno nel Sud, magari a Vibo Valentia Calabrese...
>   dove c’è il palazzo della Questura che è a un piano solo e l’ufficio per il commissario è nel seminterrato...
>   Ah ah... hai capito l’antifona: nel seminterrato... Ah
>   ah! Ah ah, t’è piaciuta? Non t’è piaciuta? Be’, sarà
>   per un’altra volta. (*Ascolta alla cornetta*) Va bene...
>   glielo riferisco subito. Bertozzo, il fra non molto calabrese commissario qui presente, ha detto che appena ci incontra a tutti e due ci dà un cazzotto sul muso! Ricevuto, passo (*altro pernacchio*), prrre! Da
>   parte di tutti e due e chiudo! (*Il Matto abbassa il ricevitore quindi si getta subito alla ricerca del materiale*)
>   «Al lavoro signor giudice, il tempo stringe». Dio, come sono emozionato! E come se dovessi dare un esame, piú di un esame di laurea maxima! Se riesco a
>   convincerli che sono un vero giudice revisore... se
>   non **smarrono**, per la miseria, sono in cattedra!

Il personaggio che dice queste parole, il Matto, prima si fa passare per un commissario di polizia al telefono e poi intende far credere a tutti che è il "giudice revisore".

Non capisco il significato di "smarrono" nel passaggio precedente. Ho letto la [voce smarrire sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/smarrire/) ma continuo a non capire. Significa che i documenti si possono perdere? Significa che gli altri possono sentirsi confusi e quindi dubitare dell'autenticità del giudice?

Comment: Questo è uno di quei casi in cui stampare un accento nel libro avrebbe reso la frase molto più chiara.

Comment: Hai ragione, @FedericoPoloni!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nella frase «se non smarrono, per la miseria, sono in cattedra!», “smarróno” è la prima persona del verbo “[smarronare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/smarronare/)”, non una persona del verbo “smarrire” (se fosse la terza plurale del presente, sarebbe “smarriscono”). Il senso è quindi “se non faccio qualche fesseria, sono in cattedra”.

Comment: *Smàrrono* è anche una forma poetica di *smarriscono* con sincope del suffisso *sco*. In questo caso però si tratta chiaramente di *smarróno*.

Comment: @DenisNardin: È forse quello che appare qui:
https://books.google.es/books?id=brYdAQAAIAAJ&dq=smarrono&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=smarrono?

Comment: @Charo Non riesco a vedere a sufficienza del libro per confermare. È un uso arcaico e poetico in ogni caso, non mi aspetterei di trovarlo in un brano contemporaneo.

Answer (score 0):

Direi dal contesto che abbia il significato di "non dire stupidaggini". È ancora termine in uso come voce dialettale in alcune zone della Toscana.